# heimdal error Decrypt integrity check failed for checksum type

Tags: authentication, kerberos, heimdal

when I try to authentication with heimdal-kdc ,I get this error in kdc log :

```
(enctype aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96) error Decrypt integrity check failed for checksum type hmac-sha1-96-aes256, key type aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96
```

and authentication failed!!!

but authentication with kinit is correct!!

my kerb5.conf is

```
[logging]
default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
krb5 = FILE:/var/log/krb5.log

[libdefaults]
    default_realm = AUTH.LANGHUA
    clockskew = 300

[realms]
    AUTH.LANGHUA = {
            kdc = AUTH.LANGHUA
    }

[domain_realm]
    .langhua = AUTH.LANGHUA

[kdc]
```

and when add this line to krb5.conf (in kdc tag)

```
require-preauth = no
```

I get this error

```
krb5_get_init_creds: Client have no reply key
```